# Variable shadowing in Java

Tags: java

I am having some doubts about this Java code. The output it gives is "furry bray". My questions:

1. Why do i get this output?
2. How can I access the String object reference "name" in ZooKeeper class?
3. If it has something to do with variable shadowing, then which variable is being shadowed?

#### Code:

```
class Mammal {
   String name = "furry ";
   String makeNoise() { return "generic noise"; }
 }
 class Zebra extends Mammal {
   String name = "stripes ";
   String makeNoise() { return "bray"; }
 }
 public class ZooKeeper {
   public static void main(String[] args) { new ZooKeeper().go(); }
   void go() {
     Mammal m = new Zebra();
     System.out.println(m.name + m.makeNoise());
     //Output comes as "furry bray". Please explain this.
     //And how can we access the name variable, the one having "stripes " in it.
     //Does it have something to do with Variable Shadowing?
   }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589274/slight-confusion-regarding-overriding-where-variables-are-concerned; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722110/overriding-variables-java; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427756/overriding-a-super-class-instance-variables

Comment: When the child and parent class both have a variable with same name child class's variable hides parent class's variable so when we try to access the variable from parent's reference by holding child's object, it will be accessed from the parent class, read more on my blog https://programmingmitra.com/2018/02/what-is-variable-shadowing-and-hiding.html

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Variables aren't polymorphic. When you access `m.name`, that will *always* use the `Mammal.name` field which is part of that object, regardless of the execution-time type of the object. If you need to get access to `Zebra.name`, you need an expression with a *compile-time* type of `Zebra`.

The `makeNoise` method is called virtually though - the implementation used at execution time *does* depend on the type of the object.

Note that if you make all your fields private - which is generally a good idea anyway - this doesn't end up being an issue.

This is actually *hiding* rather than shadowing. See [JLS section 8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3) for details on hiding, and [section 6.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) for shadowing. I can't say that I always keep the differences straight...

Comment: So, in order to the correct output, you have to create a getter method like `public String getName(){return this.name;}`

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno: You'd need to override it in `Zebra` though, with the same implementation (which would refer to a different field).

Comment: Yes, that's what I ment. You need to create that getter in Zebra, too.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thanks... I never knew.. there was a thing known as hiding of variables. :)

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno Instead of overriding getters would not it be better to create protected field `name` and public getter for `name` in base class and assign `name` in constructors of derived classes? I find this more logical and saves few key-strikes.

Comment: @PLB: Well I'd make it a *private* field in the superclass - but it depends on what's required. We don't really have a genuine use case here, with explanations of what the two separate fields are meant to mean.

Comment: If you really want to, you may modify your name variable by calling super.name in the zebra's constructor, but this would not make much sense...

Comment: @Omar: I reached the rep cap significantly before answering this question :)

Answer (score 16):

> Output comes as "furry bray". Please explain this.

`fields` in java programs are not accessed via dynamic lookup. Instead they are resolved statically while compile time. That's why you are getting `furry` for `m.name`. Whereas, `methods` in java programs are accessed via dynamic lookup. That's why you are getting `bray` for `m.makeNoise()`.

> And how can we access the name variable, the one having "stripes " in
>   it?

And if you want to access `Zebra.name` , you should type cast `m` to 'Zebra'.This would look like this:

```
System.out.println(((Zebra)m).name + m.makeNoise());
```

**UPDATE**
The phenomena that is exhibiting here is the result of [Fields Hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) rather than [variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Answer (score 9):

There is no variable overriding in Java, you declared name in both the parent and the child but you referred to it through a parent reference variable. That's why you got 'furry'.

There is overriding for methods, which is why you got bray. Because on runtime it looked at the real object in the heap and saw it's a Zebra.

Answer (score 4):

Variable names in Java are resolved by the reference type, not the object they are referencing. So, m.name refers to the variable name in Mammal even dough m is a Zebra.

Answer (score 3):

It happened because your field `name` from `Mammal` is just **hidden** by `name` field from `Zebra`. You can then access it simply by casting to required type.
On the other side `makeNoise()` method **overrides** same method from parent so you can't access implementation from parent anymore.