# Can we override instance members in Java?

Tags: java

Can we override instance/static members in Java?
What could happen if we did?

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589274/slight-confusion-regarding-overriding-where-variables-are-concerned

Comment: install any editor say eclipse - https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/lunasr2  and try it yourself!! Both of your doubts will be instantly clarified

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Child.hello();
     }

     static class Parent{
         public static int i = 0;

         public static void hello(){
             System.out.println("hello");
         }
     }

        static class Child extends Parent{
         public static int i = 1;

         public static void hello(){
             System.out.println("world");
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No we can't override instance/static fields in java. Also static methods can't be overridden.