# Why does changing the type lead to different usage of members?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, member

So I was testing with some code snippets to wrap my head around the concept of inheritance, when I came across this - for me - strange phenomenon.

So first I was testing this simple code:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();

        System.out.println("age = " + bar.age);

        bar.test();
    }
}

class Foo{
    int age = 2;

    void test(){
        System.out.println("TEST FOO");
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo{
    int age = 4;

    void test(){
        System.out.println("TEST BAR");
    }
}
```

And the output was as I expected:

```
age = 4
TEST BAR
```

Then I made a small change to line 3, where I changed the type `Bar` to `Foo` like this:

```
Foo bar = new Bar();
```

Now when I run the code, it gives me an output I believe is weird:

```
age = 2
TEST BAR
```

How does it happen that the code `bar.age` is now using the `age` member of the `Foo` class (which makes sense), while `bar.test();` still uses the method of the `Bar` class (and not from Foo as that is what the type is)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589274/slight-confusion-regarding-overriding-where-variables-are-concerned or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722110/overriding-member-variables-in-java

Comment: @RC. Interesting reads, was looking for that. Thanks.

Comment: Beside the technical aspect: doing so this is **not** OOP since it violates the most important OO principle: *information hiding / encapsulation*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `age` in `Bar` *shadows* the `age` in `Foo`.

Furthermore, fields are **not** polymorphic (cf. functions).

So when you write `Foo bar = new Bar();`, the *static* type of `bar` is used when accessing the field `age`, to return 2. And the *dynamic* type of `bar` is used when deciding which override of `test()` to call, and that's a `Bar` type.

Comment: I understand that it prints `age = 2`. But then I still don't get why it is calling `Bar.test();` while it is op type `Foo`.

Comment: @moffeltje: added that. The function is polymorphic.

Answer (score 4):

Because you have defined two different age fields, one in each class. Fields are not overridden.