# Property with same name in Child class java

Tags: java, oop

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  protected int num = 12;

  public void callme()
  {
    System.out.print(this.num);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    HelloWorld myObject1 = new HelloWorld();
    myObject1.callme();
    OtherClass myObject2 = new OtherClass();
    myObject2.callme();
  }
}


public class OtherClass extends HelloWorld
{
  protected int num = 14;
}
```

Why the output is "1212" instead of "1214"? In php its "1214" but not viceversa in java. What's the logic behind that?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP? Why the PHP tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589274/slight-confusion-regarding-overriding-where-variables-are-concerned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`callme()` method is defined only in the base class, and therefore `return this.num;` returns the instance variable of the base class.

There is no overriding of instance variables in Java.

If you'd override that method in the sub-class, by adding

```
public void callme()
{
    System.out.print(this.num);
}
```

to `OtherClass`, `myObject2.callme();` will return 14, since it will execute `callme()` method of the sub-class, and therefore access the sub-class instance variable.