# Method overriding another method is throwing NullPointerException even when constructor is already initialized

Tags: java

I'm trying to override a `toString` method from a parent class but whenever I try to run the program, it throws a `NullPointerException` even though my constructors are already initialized. The `Car` class that extends `Vehicle` is where the problem is. Ehen I remove the `spec.getNoOfDoors` the program runs.

Here are my classes:

**Vehicle:**

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private String serialNo;
    private Double price;
    private Integer size;
    VehicleSpec spec;

    public Vehicle(String serialNo, double price, int size, VehicleSpec spec) {
        this.serialNo = serialNo;
        this.price = price;
        this.size = size;
        this.spec = spec;
    }

    ... // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s - %s, Color: %s - Serial No.: %s - Price: %s - Size: %s - ", spec.getBrand(), spec.getModel(), spec.getColor(), this.serialNo, this.price, this.size);
    }
}
```

**Car:**

```
public class Car extends Vehicle{
    CarSpec spec;

    public Car(CarSpec spec, String serialNo, double price, int size) {
        super(serialNo, price, size, spec);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(super.toString() + "Door: %d", spec.getNoOfDoors()); //<- this is where the problem is..
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.inventory.main.Car.toString(Car.java:12)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
at com.inventory.main.CarInventorySearch.main(CarInventorySearch.java:16)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: This is a large code dump, and you should at least tell us which line has the problem.

Comment: Removed the other codes, the problem is in the Car class, even though I already initialized the noOfDoors in the constructor, it still throws null pointer exception.

Comment: @Anthony Post your error logs. In which line does the exception occurs? Did you even go through the link: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but have you actually set the CarSpec spec; variable in the car class?

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet, but this contains a value when I initialized the constructor.

Comment: Maybe you should do this in the Car constructor: `this.spec = spec;`

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet, I already did that in the Vehicle class constractor.

Comment: Your Car class contains a field named `spec`, which hides the field `spec` in the `Vehicle` class. So you have two fields called `spec` and you have to assign both a value.

Comment: @Sulphate, yes I have that in the Car class.

Comment: @Anthony In the `toString( )` method of `Car` class you are doing `spec.getNoOfDoors( )`. This `spec` is the one defined above the constructor and has never been initialized. It currently refers to `null`. You have to initialize it in the `Car`'s constructor

Comment: @dunni, I also have a VehicleSpec class whic is the parent class of CarSpec class. I posted all my classes earlier but I was told that it was a huge code dump so I deleted it.

Comment: Doesn't matter in this case. The two spec fields are still different fields.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet, but the Car's constructor takes properties from CarSpec's constructor, do you think it would help if I post those classes here so you can see?

Comment: @Anthony You might want to follow the link in my answer to clear up the confusion about the fact that you have two different `spec` properties and how **hiding** works in Java.

Comment: @Keiwan, yes, thanks for the link.

Comment: @Anthony No problem. I'm glad it helped.

Comment: @Keiwan, I've been studying java for almost 4 weeks now, and I am beginning to realize why most people loves to hate it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the misconception is that the

```
CarSpec spec;
```

is somehow meant to be same (or override) the

```
VehicleSpec spec;
```

which is declared and initialized in the superclass (`Vehicle`). However, this is [**not** the case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10722142/6214222).

These are two **different** properties, of which you will only be able to access the `spec` of type `CarSpec` in the subclass. This `spec` will not be initialized, just because you have initialized the `VehicleSpec spec` in your superclass.

So you need to initialize this `spec` in the constructor of the subclass like

```
this.spec = spec;
```

Note that this behaviour is **hiding** and not *overriding*. Variables, unlike methods, are resolved at **compile-time** and not at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
    public class Car extends Vehicle{
//Below 'spec' is local for Car and not have the reference Vehicle class 'spec'
    CarSpec spec;

    public Car(CarSpec spec, String serialNo, double price, int size) {
        super(serialNo, price, size, spec);
        //Local 'spec' assigned by the spec received from constructor and the same in Vehicle 
        this.spec = spec;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(super.toString() + "Door: %d", spec.getNoOfDoors()); //<- this is where the problem is..
    }
```