# Calling a method and a variable of a subclass extended from a superclass

Tags: java, casting, subclass, extends, superclass

```
class X {              //Super class
    int a=10;
    public void data() {
        int b=10;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}

class Y extends X {    //Subclass
    int a=20;
    public void data() {
        int b=20;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}



public class Casting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x = new Y();
        System.out.println(x.a);   //Prints a=10 : Value of superclass
        x.data();                  //Prints b=20 : Value of subclass
    }
}
```

I know that this has something to do with **Upcasting** and **Downcasting**. But in that case shouldn't both the values be of the same class.

**Edit:** 
Fixed it!
Turns out, when

> X x = new Y();

is executed, **x** holds the original value of its fields(variables) but retains the value of any method that is overridden in the subclass.

Therefore, the instance **x** holds:

> a=10
>
> public void data() {
>
> int b=20;
>
> System.put.println(b);
>
> }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722110/overriding-member-variables-in-java

Comment: variables are never overloaded. Use methods for overloading.