# Is it possible to give a value to a child class in its parent class in Java?

Tags: java, parent-child

I searched a lot for this but couldn't find it anywhere, but if you think that it had been asked before, please send me the link.

I have a parent class called chesspiece and I have 6 child classes: 
Pawn with the value of 1, 
Knight with the value of 2, 
Bishop with the value of 3, 
Rook with the value of 5, 
Queen with the value of 9
and king with the value of 1000.

I have two instance variable: value and the color of the piece

I want to know is it possible to say if you have the value of 1 you belong to the pawn class or if you have the value of 2, you belong to the knight class.
So, right now I'm doing this using a method but it only returns a String and nothing more. Here's my code:

```
public class ChessPiece {
    private boolean     isWhite;
    private int         value;

    public ChessPiece (boolean isWhite, int value) {
        this.isWhite = isWhite;
        this.value = value;
    }
public String getNamebyValue() {
        switch (value) {
          case 1:
            return "Pawn";
          case 2:
            return "Knight";
          case 3:
            return "Bishop";
          case 5:
            return "Rook";
          case 9:
            return "Queen";
          case 1000:
            return "King";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And here's my child class:

```
public class Bishop extends ChessPiece {

    public Bishop(boolean isWhite) {
        super(isWhite, 3);

    }
```

Comment: *it only returns a String* What else did you expect to get?

Comment: What's the exact question? Do you want to return a `Class` instance- meaning if its 1 then the return type should be an object of class Pawn?

Comment: well, is it possible to do it in the constructor?

Comment: mohd shoaib  I want to know is it possible to say if you have the value of 1 you belong to the pawn class or if you have the value of 2, you belong to the knight class

Comment: In that case, I have given the answer below. Please try that. Please Accept the answer if it works

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. Appreciate it.

Comment: It really sounds like what you want is an `enum`.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:

**ChessPiece.java**

```
public class ChessPiece {
    private boolean     isWhite;
    private int         value;
    private String      name;

    public ChessPiece (boolean isWhite) {
        this.isWhite = isWhite;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

}
```

**Bishop.java**

```
public class Bishop extends ChessPiece {

    public Bishop(boolean isWhite) {
        super(isWhite);
        this.name = "Bishop";
        this.value = 3;
    }
    ...
}
```

In other words, let "class inheritance" do as much of the work as possible for you.

To answer your question: it's possible to *share* a variable between the parent and subclasses (as shown above).

It's also possible to *override* member variables in the child.  Look here: [Overriding member variables in Java ( Variable Hiding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722110/overriding-member-variables-in-java-variable-hiding)

It all depends on your design - on your requirements, and on how you choose to implement those requirements.

Comment: PS: I'm not sure there's much value in the "value" member (if a chess piece has a "type", like "Bishop", what's the point of "value=3"?).  But I like Guy's suggestion [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60690398/3135317).  If you need "value", then "enum" is better (more appropriate) than "int".

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create chess for every piece type, there isn't enough difference between them. Use `enum` instead

```
public class ChessPiece {
    private boolean isWhite;
    private ChessPieceType pieceType;

    enum ChessPieceType {
        Pawn(1),
        Knight(2),
        Bishop(3),
        //...
        King(1000);

        private int value;

        private ChessPieceType(int value) { 
            this.value = value; 
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }
   }

    public ChessPiece (ChessPieceType type, boolean isWhite) {
        this.pieceType = type;
        this.isWhite = isWhite;
    }

    public ChessPieceType getPieceType() {
        return this.pieceType;
    }
}
```

Uses

```
ChessPiece piece = new ChessPiece(ChessPiece.ChessPieceType.Bishop, true);
ChessPiece.ChessPieceType pieceType = piece.getPieceType();

System.out.println(pieceType); //Bishop
System.out.println(pieceType.getValue()); //3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but not the way you're coding it.

I would suggest having the method return a type of ChessPiece instead of a String, and then instantiating the type with calling that method and a number.

```
  public class ChessPiece {
private boolean     isWhite;
private int         value;

public ChessPiece (boolean isWhite, int value) {
    this.isWhite = isWhite;
    this.value = value;
}
public ChessPiece getNamebyValue(int value) {
    switch (value) {
      case 1:
        return new Pawn();
        break;
      case 2:
        return new Knight();
      break;
       case 3:
        return new Bishop();
        break;
      case 5:
        return new Rook();
       break;
      case 9:
        return new Queen();
       break;
      case 1000:
        return new King();
      break;
      default:
      return new ChessPiece();
      break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then....

```
       ChessPiece cp= new getNameByValue(1000);
```

That will return an object of type King.

Also, if you don't have break statements in your switch, it will simply return the last value as it goes through each statement until there is a break.

Comment: Are you using Java? `break` is not a method (`break()`)

Comment: You're right.  I edited it.   I don't know how that slipped my mind.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly you may want to look at **Factory Design Pattern** you will send a function the "recipe" to create your object (in your case the value) and return an appropriate object

Answer (score -1):

In that case change the `getNamebyValue()` as below:

```
public ChessPiece getNamebyValue() {
    switch (value) {
      case 1:
        return new Pawn();
      case 2:
        return new Knight();
      case 3:
        return new Bishop();
      case 5:
        return new Rook()";
      case 9:
        return new Queen();
      case 1000:
        return new King();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

and create the subclasses as you shown for `Bishop`

Comment: If this didn't have any break statements, wouldn't it simply just return a King every time?

Comment: A return statement with all the case statements will safeguard that.  In case of no match, then only null will be returned

Comment: There should be a `break` statement to immediately come out if the switch once a match is found.