# Why Runtime Poymorphism behavior changes for Class variables

Tags: java, polymorphism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hiding instance variables of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794621/hiding-instance-variables-of-a-class)

I have below class

**AbstractTest**

```
public abstract class AbstractTest {
 protected int testVar = 10;
}
```

**Test**

```
public class Test extends AbstractTest {
int testVar = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AbstractTest test = new Test();
    System.out.println(test.testVar);//Prints 10

    Test secondTest = new Test();
    System.out.println(secondTest.testVar);//Prints 5
}
}
```

Why above program prints `10` for first case and `5` for second case though it is object of same class i.e. `Test()`?

**Update:**

`I am now confused about how memory is allocated to Object and its variables. As instance variable is getting changed based on Class which is  behaviour of Static?`

**Update:1**

`Every object will have two variables so question of same memory allocation does not comes in to picture. Thanks.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is defined in [JLS 15.11.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1-210)

> [In the expression `Primary.Identifier`], only the type of the Primary expression, not the class of the actual object referred to at run-time, is used in determining which field to use.

Comment: Thanks. That's a very clear explanation. I guess now I clearly  understand why to define variables private.

Comment: Can you please answer updated question also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand your additional question.

Answer (score 1):

**The variable is used based upon the reference of the class.** So when `AbstractTest` reference is used `testVar` is used from `AbstractTest` class.

Answer (score 1):

One hard & fast rule:

**The fields are used of reference types, while methods are used of actual object.**

`test` is reference of `AbstractTest`, so base class field is used.

`secondTest` is a reference of `derive class`, so derived class field is used.