# Explanation of the output

Tags: java

The question might be a very basic one. I am new to Java so please bear with me.
My code:

```
class A
{
     int b=10;

     A()
     {
          this.b=7;
     }

     int f()
     {
          return b;
     }
}

class B extends A{ int b; }

class Test
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          A a=new B();
           System.out.println(a.f());
     }
}
```

Why is the output 7? Doesn't class B get its own instance variable `b`?

Comment: Seems like variable shadowing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would but the function `f` can only see the version of `b` that is in `A`. Thus the function returns 7.

If you were to copy the function `f` into the `class B` you would see the member `b` of the `class B` being returned.

As [Hiding instance variables of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794621/hiding-instance-variables-of-a-class) explains, Java variables are not polymorphic. The 2 `b` variables are 2 different variables as you would expect, but when you call the function `A.f` it can only see the one `b` variable that `A` has. So it returns `A.b` and NOT `B.b`.

So to answer your question, class B DOES get its own instance variable `b`, and it is completely independant of `A.b` but you currently have no way to access it so you cannot see its value.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more as to why or point me where I can read more? Sorry new to Java.

Comment: Is function f visible in class B?

Comment: `class B extends A` thats means whatever class A has will be available to class B, unless `f()` is private or not in same package.

Comment: @IanMcGrath Default access modifier in java is [package-private](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), so it will be accessible as long as B and Test are in the same package as A, which looks like it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your type reference is `A`:

```
A a = new B();
```

Thus instance fields/static fields and static methods will be provided from `A`, as long as concerned method (in your case `f()`) isn't overriden by `B`.

In other languages, as Scala, variables can be redefined in subclasses and targeted even from a supertype reference.