# Explain the functioning of "this" Keyword and the concept of Instance Variable Hiding by using "this" keyword in java

Tags: java, keyword

I have been learning **Java** from *Java 2: Complete Reference, 5th Edition*. I couldn't understand the exact of purpose `this` keyword and the concept of instance variable hiding. please explain me with example.

Comment: See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) about `this` :)

Comment: See [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794621/hiding-instance-variables-of-a-class for instance variable hiding

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for tutoring in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The exact purpose of this is to remove ambiguity from local variable from your field variables.`

**this** is an alias or a name for the current instance inside the instance. It is useful for disambiguating instance variables from locals (including parameters), but it can be used by itself to simply refer to member variables and methods, invoke other constructor overloads, or simply to refer to the instance. Some examples of applicable uses (not exhaustive):

```
class Foo
{
 private int bar; 

 public Foo() {
      this(42); // invoke parameterized constructor
 }

 public Foo(int bar) {
     this.bar = bar; // disambiguate 
 }

 public void frob() {
      this.baz(); // used "just because"
 }

 private void baz() {
      System.out.println("whatever");
 }

}
```

also read [this keyword](http://www.javatpoint.com/this-keyword) and also [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) link

Comment: It's always better to point to the official docs, rather than some random blog.

Comment: Ok.I have edited my answer and added one more link :)