# How do I get my 2 objects and call a function passing a variable through it?

Tags: java, object, accessor

In my driver class CarRaceSim in the function race I call both of my objects car1 and car2. Then I call the accelerate and brake function from my CarRace class that is supposed to add and subtract a random number from the speed variable that is passed in accelerate and brake. The speed variable is an int that the user assigns a value to. However, when I call the function and print it out it displays only what the user put in. The program in general is supposed to simulate 5 races in which each lap (loop 5 times) the car accelerates and brakes which is why I called accelerate and brake for both cars. How can I get accelerate and brake to function properly?

```
package carrace;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 *
 * @author Daniel
 */
public class CarRace {

    int year, speed;
    String model, make;


    // default constructor
    public CarRace(){
        year = 2000;
        model = "";
        make = "";
        speed = 0;
    }

    // non-default constuctor
    public CarRace(int aYear, String aModel, String aMake, int aSpeed){
        this.year = aYear;
        this.model = aModel;
        this.make = aMake;
        this.speed = aSpeed;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public void accelerate(int speed){
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        int ranNum;

        ranNum = randomNum.nextInt(26) + 5;
        speed += ranNum; 
    }

    public void brake(int speed){
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        int ranNum;

        ranNum = randomNum.nextInt(26) + 5;
        speed -= ranNum; 
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "The year of the car is " + year + ", the model of the car is " + model + ", the make of the car is " + make + ", and the initial speed is " + speed + ".\n";
    }
}
```

---

```
package carrace;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Daniel
 */
public class CarRaceSim {

    public static CarRace car1;
    public static CarRace car2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to the car simulation program!");
        System.out.println("You will now begin to create your two cars to race, good luck!\n\n");

        createCar(1);
        createCar(2);

        race(car1, car2);
    }

    public static void createCar(int carCreation){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int year = 0;
        String model;
        String make;
        int speed = 0;

        do{
            if (carCreation == 1)
                System.out.println("Create your first car!");
            else
                System.out.println("Create your second car!");

            System.out.println("What year is your car?");
            year = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println("What model is your car?");
            model = keyboard.next();

            System.out.println("What make is your car?");
            make = keyboard.next();

            System.out.println("What speed is your car initially starting at? (0-60)");
            speed= keyboard.nextInt();

            if(speed < 0){
                System.out.println("You can not begin at a negative speed, please choose between 0-60.");
            }
            else if(speed > 60){
                System.out.println("You can not start above 60, please choose between 0-60.");
            }          

        }while(speed <= 0 && speed >= 60);

        if(carCreation == 1){
            car1 = new CarRace(year, model, make, speed);
            System.out.println(car1);
        }
        else{
            car2 = new CarRace(year, model, make, speed);
            System.out.println(car2);
        }    

    }

    public static void race(CarRace carUno, CarRace carDue){

        for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){

            System.out.println("Lap " + i);

            System.out.println("Car 1's stats:");
            car1.accelerate(car1.getSpeed());
            System.out.println(car1.getSpeed());
            car1.brake(car1.getSpeed());
            System.out.println(car1.getSpeed());

            System.out.println("Car 2's stats:");
            car2.accelerate(car2.getSpeed());
            System.out.println(car2.getSpeed());
            car2.brake(car2.getSpeed());
            System.out.println(car2.getSpeed() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `accelerate()` function you assign a value to the local variable `speed`. What you want to assign to is the class variable `this.speed`, just like you do in your other methods (like `setMake()` for example).

In other words change

```
speed += ranNum;
```

to

```
this.speed += ranNum;
```

Do the same for your brake function.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, thank you I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The value that you change in `accelerate()` and `brake()` methods is updated on the variable that you passing not on the speed variable of class. 
To assign new value to speed variable of class add following line in your `accelerate()` and `brake()` methods:

```
//for accelerate() method
//add below line after speed += ranNum;
this.speed = speed;

//for brake() method
//add below line after speed -= ranNum;
this.speed = speed;
```

Also see [Instance Variable Hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857771/explain-the-functioning-of-this-keyword-and-the-concept-of-instance-variable-h?lq=1) for further explanation on why you need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your accelerate method as following:

```
public void accelerate(int speed){
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        int ranNum;

        ranNum = randomNum.nextInt(26) + 5;
        this.speed += ranNum; 
    }
```

Similarly u have to change brake method