# initialization blocks in polymorphism

Tags: java, scjp

I have a Doubt

when we initialize our instance variables in Instance initialization block(s) in case of inheritance do they override the value of variable?

For example

```
class A{
int x;
} 
class B extends A{
int x = 10;
}

public class C{
public static void main(String[] args){
A K = new B();
System.out.println(K.x); 
}
}

o/p : 0
```

However when i use initialization blocks

```
class A{
int x;
{x = 15;}
} 
class B extends A{
{x=20;}
}

public class C{
public static void main(String[] args){
A K = new B();
System.out.println(K.x); 
}
}

OUTPUT 20
```

Why its so? why my initialization block(s) are affecting instance variables ? Moreover , i know that blocks are called when we make object but still the variable at output should correspond to variable type i.e A K (K should give value corresponding to class A)

Comment: What would you expect them to do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794621/hiding-instance-variables-of-a-class

Comment: i want in 2nd program to show up OUTPUT: 15

Answer (score 1):

You can override methods only, not variables. This code isn't "overriding" instance variables.

The first example has a different variables named x defined for A and B, making the variable an A means you see the variable defined for A ([see the link provided by paulk23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794621/hiding-instance-variables-of-a-class)). In the second there is only one instance variable x which is visible to the subclass, the instance initializer assigns a value to an existing variable.

Comment: if i make it private it wont be visible in class B.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you have two declarations of x, and in the second you only have one. In the second example, try changing B to:

```
class B extends A {
    int x;
    { x=20; }
}
```

and you'll see the same behaviour as the first example: B defines a new variable that has an independent value from the one in A.