# How and why inheritance of methods differ from inheritance of variables?

Tags: java, inheritance

while preparing myself for OCJP exam i stumbled upon one question i am unable to wrap my mind around. Here's (a bit modified by me) code from a question:

```
class Foo {
    public int a = 3;
    public void addFive() {
        a += 5;
        System.out.print("f ");
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public int a = 8;
    public void addFive() {
        a += 5;
        System.out.print("b ");
    }
}

public class TestInheritance {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        // part 1
        Foo f = new Bar();
        f.addFive();
        System.out.println(f.a);

        // part 2
        Bar b = new Bar();
        b.addFive();
        System.out.println(b.a);
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
b 3
b 13
```

Part 2 i can understand. Nothing surprising here. However part 1 does not let me sleep at night. I understand why `Bar.addFive` was run but why in part 1 `f.a` prints `Foo.a` when I used `new Bar()` to instantiate an object? It looks like inheritance works quite different for methods than for variables. What am i missing here to understand that concept? What am I failing in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding instance variables of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794621/hiding-instance-variables-of-a-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It looks like inheritance works quite different for methods then for variables.

More precisely, inheritance does not make variables polymorphic. When you declare an identical method, a method in the derived class overrides the method in the base. When you declare an identical variable, the variable in the base class is hidden by the variable in the derived class.

In your example, `Bar` has two variables `a`, but only one method `addFive()`. Essentially, each `Bar` object holds two integers - `Foo.a` and `Bar.a`. These two are separate variables. However, the `addFive` method is the one defined in `Bar`, because it overrides (replaces) `addFive` from `Foo`.

Note that Java lets `Bar` access `Foo.addFive` by calling `super.addFive()`, but users of `Bar` lack this possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Variables are not polymorphic. only methods are.

However you can access them from the parent class if they are declared `protected` or `public` or through setters and getters

Answer (score 0):

```
 Foo f = new Bar();
```

That line alone means Access the implementations in Bar and members from Foo  :)

So you'll get `a` from `Foo` and the method implementations from `Bar`

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand the part 1 you need to understand the difference between static and dynamic binding.

Static binding occurs during compile time and private, final and static methods and variables uses static binding. Static binding uses Type(Class)  information for binding.

Based on the above definition when the line  Foo f = new Bar(); get compiled, the variable a is initialized 3.

Methods are resolved using Dynamic binding and Dynamic binding uses Object to resolve binding.
Since the object is of the Class Bar() the addFive() method of the Bar class is executed. Hence the output b3