# Understanding Java's inheritance model

Tags: java, inheritance

Example code:

```
public class Parent {
  String name = "Parent";

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  String name = "Child";

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

public class Tester {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Parent p = new Child();
    Child  c = new Child();
    System.out.println("p.name is " + p.name); // prints out "Parent"
    System.out.println("c.name is " + c.name); // prints out "Child"
    System.out.println("p.getName() is " + p.getName()); // prints out "Child"
    System.out.println("c.getName() is " + c.getName()); // prints out "Child"
  }
}
```

**My Understanding So Far**

So far, my understanding of inheritance in Java allows me to understand why the 3rd and 4th `println` statements produce "Child" as an output. At compile time, the compiler makes sure that `getName` method is defined in the type of the reference variable but during runtime is when which version `getName` is determined. And since both reference variables actually refer to a `Child` object, Child's `getName` is invoked.

**Question 1**

However, why is it that when you access the instance variable directly, the behavior is different from how methods are accessed? In particular, I find it strange that `p.name` returns "Parent" instead of "Child".

**Question 2**

In a similar vein, if I commented out the `getName` function in the `Child` class and re-ran the code in `Tester`, I'm surprised to see that `p.getName()` and `c.getName()` return "Parent" instead of "Child".

Can someone help elaborate on these 2 questions?

Comment: The whole problem you do have is that you think you can overwrite variables  aswell, but you can´t. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794621/hiding-instance-variables-of-a-class)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link @KevinEsche! How does this apply for my 2nd question?

Comment: Also, inheritance describes an *is a* relation. For this reason the `Parent` / `Child` analogy is terribly bad. A `Child` is *not* a `Parent`.

Comment: @wmock, because the same name of the variable doesn´t make them logically connected. The function get name wont look for a variable with the name `name`. It specificly refers to the on it finds in the class where the method is defined (or any class it is inheriting from if it is in the scope of visiblity)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @aioobe - you're completely right. In my haste to understanding the mechanisms behind Java's inheritance model, I definitely chose an analogy that isn't great. However, I'm more concerned with Question 2 and why both cases return the Parent class' instance variable value instead of the Child class' value.

Comment: @KevinEsche so what you're saying is that once the method to be invoked is determined, if that method refers to instance variables, it will only look at that class' or class' superclasses instance variables right?

Comment: Did you mean "both cases return the child's values? All methods in Java are virtual. Direct field access can't be overridden. What this means is that it is the runtime type that decides which method gets called and the compile time (static) type that decides which field is accessed.

Comment: @aioobe I'm not entirely sure I know what you mean by "All methods in Java are virtual." I guess I find it weird that if I comment out "getName" in the Child class, my 3rd and 4th println statements print out "Parent" even though the underlying object in both cases is a Child instance.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between static and runtime types? (`p` has static type `Parent` and runtime type `Child` and `c` has static type `Child` and runtime type `Chald`.) It is the *compiler* that decides which field to access, i.e. field access depends on the static type. (If you look at the compiled bytecode, `p.name` will refer to `Parent.name`.) It is the VM that decides which method to call, i.e. method access depends on the runtime type.

Comment: @aioobe thanks for the clarification - this is much clearer to me now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables can not be overridden in Java. What you have done is called hiding a variable (the variable `name` in `Parent` is difficult to access)

The way to understand the behavior you are describing is to think of `name` as only the name of the variable, not an actual variable. When used in the context (in terms of code, not actual type of a variable) of `Parent` it points to a different variable than when used in the context of `Child`.

When calling `c.name` or `p.name` you tell the program which context to use, because the variables `c` and `p` are declared respectively of type `Child` and `Parent`. When using it in a method inside the class the variable of the current class is used.

If you want to use the `Parent.name` in a child class you will have to cast it:

```
System.out.println("c.name is " + ((Parent) c).name);
```

For a method, the function called is always that of the actual type of the variable being called. In your case, regardless of calling it from `Tester`, `Parent` or `Client`.

Of course it is best not to hide variables at all, an use different names for different variables.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Thirler - this makes sense to me now.