# Could a superclass differ to subclasses?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

Lets say we have:

1) Superclass containing a string parameter: companyName
2) Subclasses containing string parameters: firstName, lastName

If we have subClassA, subClassB, subClassC, subClassD, etc. Can these subclasses have same superclass, but with different strings companyName, or the companyName meaning/value will be the same for every subclass no matter what?

Comment: Do you understand the distinction between Classes and Instances?

Comment: That could have been my bad explanation. What I meant was, the subClasses are all instances of one particular class, which extends a superclass.

Comment: Yep. That's what a subclass is alright. So do all those subclasses share the same instance of the superclass ?

Comment: Perhaps you are talking about "hiding fields" like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7794621)

Comment: Yes Is it possible to instance a superclass, so it is unique(different string meanings) to particular instances of subclasses?

Comment: David, no. Lets say we have company A and company B. Is it possible to have 2 instances of a superclass, 1 containing a string companyName = A, another containing a string companyName = B? Or the superclass string companyName would contain either A or B (only 1 of them) for every subclass instance it has?

Comment: It is absolutely possible and very common, @Lukas. See my answer for code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every instance of the parent class can have a different value for `companyName` whether it's of a subtype or not.

```
public class Parent {
  private final String companyName;

  public Parent(String name) {
    this.companyName = name;      // ignoring error-checking here
  }

  public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
  }
}

public class Subsidiary extends Parent {
  private final String subsidiaryName;

  public Subsidiary(String parentName, String subsidiaryName) {
    super(parentName);
    this.subsidiaryName = subsidiaryName;
  }

  public String getSubsidiaryName() {
    return subsidiaryName;
  }
}
```

In some client code you can call:

```
Subsidiary subsidiary = new Subsidiary("Holdings, Inc.", "Puppet");
System.out.println(subsidiary.getCompanyName() + " owns "
    + subsidiary.getSubsidiaryName());
```

You see, the child-type object inherits the accessor method `getCompanyName` that gives it access to the information in the parent section of the object.

Comment: Subclass instances don't _have_ superclass instances, they _are_ superclass instances​, and AFAICT I hit the question as phrased, which was not ""Can n subclass instances have the same superclass instance?", so I have no clue how you arrived at that formulation.

Comment: @LewBloch Thank you, this answered and solved my issues!